# Error in creating file to save the pdf in Rstudio

Tags: r

When I want to create a pdf file to save the heatmap in Rstudio this error occurs:

```
pdf("Custom Office Templates/")
Error in pdf("Custom Office Templates/") : 
  cannot open file 'Custom Office Templates/'
```

what is the solution?

Comment: "Custom Office Templates/" seems to be the name of a folder, not a file. Use a file name instead, e.g., `pdf("Custom Office Templates/myfile.pdf").